# Zend_Form: Duplicate decorator IDs on subforms

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using Zend_Form from Zend Framework 1.10.6 to render a html form. In this form 'z', there's a subform with a field 'a'. The subform is added to the main form twice, once with the name 'x' and once as 'y'.

Below is the html rendered by the Zend_Form-object.

```
<form id="z" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="">
 <dl class="zend_form">
  <dt id="x-label">&#160;</dt>
  <dd id="x-element">
   <fieldset id="fieldset-x">
    <dl>
     <dt id="a-label"><label for="x-a" class="required">A</label></dt>
     <dd id="a-element"><input type="text" name="x[a]" id="x-a" value="" /></dd>
    </dl>
   </fieldset>
  </dd>

  <dt id="y-label">&#160;</dt>
  <dd id="y-element">
   <fieldset id="fieldset-y">
    <dl>
     <dt id="a-label"><label for="y-a" class="optional">A</label></dt>
     <dd id="a-element"><input type="text" name="y[a]" id="y-a" value="" /></dd>
    </dl>
   </fieldset>
  </dd>

  <dt id="submit-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="submit-element"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></dd>
 </dl>
</form>
```

The only problem is now that the standard decorator (`<dt>`, `<dd>`) generates duplicate IDs. Why aren't these IDs prefixed with the subform name and a dash, like the IDs of the input fields are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why they aren't prefixed but to get around it, I'd just set my own custom decorators on the elements. This article may help http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450